# ReduxForm - Dynamic connect parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using ReduxForm with two types of form :

- inside Modals
- inside Tabs.

Depends of the form' type, I have to adapt my reduxForm 'connect' parameter.

With Tab, I need :

- destroyOnUnmount
- enableReinitialize
- [ ... ]

With Modal, I dont want them.

My Form is getting form's type by Props, but I can't use it to adapt my reduxForm.

```
export defaut ReduxForm({
   form : 'testForm',
   destroyOnUnmount : false,
   enableReinitialize: true ,
   [...] 
  })(MyForm)
```

I have no idea how to adapt this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about what you're asking about exactly, but I think I have a pretty good clue: You want to be able to add the `destroyOnUnmount` and `enableReinitialize` props if your form is inside a Tab and not add them if your form is inside a modal, right?

You can do it by wrapping your `reduxForm` -wrapped component with `connect` from `react-redux` and then using `mapStateToProps` to determine which prop values to pass in for `redux-form`. Something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const { insideTab } = ownProps

  return {
    ...ownProps,
    destroyOnUnmount: !insideTab,
    enableReinitialize: !!insideTab
  }
}

export default connect(mapStaToProps)(
  ReduxForm({ form : 'testForm' })(MyForm)
)
```

which you can then use like this

```
// this creates a container with
// destroyOnUnmount=false
// and
// enableReinitialize=true
<MyFormContainer insideTab />

// this creates a container with
// destroyOnUnmount=true
// and
// enableReinitialize=false
<MyFormContainer />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting the redux form, export a function that returns it:

```
export default isTab => ReduxForm({
  form : 'testForm',
  destroyOnUnmount : !!isTab,
  enableReinitialize: !!isTab ,
  [...] 
})(MyForm)
```

then

```
import makeMyForm from 'MyForm'
const TabForm = makeMyForm(true);
const ModalForm = makeMyForm();
```